# How resolve -API call error https://a.blazemeter.com/api/latest/proxy: {'code': 401, 'message': 'Unauthorized'}

Tags: jmeter

I have one selenium script. Now I want it to convert into a JMX file. Here I used the proxy2jmx converter. I also created an account in Blazemeter. I have one token and a secret key, those values provide in the .bzt-rc file.
Now I provide one config yml file -

execution:

- executor: selenium

  iterations: 1

  scenario: sel

scenarios:

sel:

```
script: F:\Taurus\HelloSelenium.java
```

services:

- module: proxy2jmx
  modules:

proxy2jmx:

token: 707ab10114456ad7af13827f

When execute this file It return Error message-->11:21:24 ERROR: Network Error: API call error https://a.blazemeter.com/api/latest/proxy: {'code': 401, 'message': 'Unauthorized'}
11:21:24 INFO: Post-processing...
11:21:24 INFO: Will not pick converted JMX due to exception: API call error https://a.blazemeter.com/api/latest/proxy: {'code': 401, 'message': 'Unauthorized'}

How is it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way of providing token is

```
modules:
  blazemeter:
    token: 756a1345d1c8258a739dd260:1c2f53d2612dc64cb4c9dade311f351916b9e391330c9f6d1a2e1e36da76cabc44be9ce6
```

More information:

- [BlazeMeter Reporting Service - Personalized Usage](https://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/#Personalized-Usage)
- [BlazeMeter API keys](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002213289-BlazeMeter-API-keys-)

Comment: I already passed this in the .bzt-rc file.  Can this be needed to pass in yml file also?and please can you mention how proxy2jmx module pass